# hibernate map view with one to many relations

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, one-to-many, sql-view

I'm mapping sql view to entity class with hibernate `@Subselect` annotation.
Basically, it looks somewhat like this:

```
@Subselect(
    "SELECT table1.*, table2.id as tid FROM " 
   + "table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table2.field = table1.field"
)
@Entity
@Immutable
class Entity {
    // fields
}
```

When the join works i may get something like the following

```
========================================
| table1.id | table1.field | table2.id |
========================================
|         1 |            1 |         1 |
========================================
|         1 |            1 |         2 |
========================================
```

So several records in table2 can join to one row in table1. This is fine, however in java Entity I want to map it as one to many relationship(one entity to many table2 enities), here's what I wrote, which worked for others kind of relationships:

```
@Subselect(
    "SELECT table1.*, table2.id as tid FROM " 
   + "table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table2.field = table1.field"
)
@Entity
@Immutable
class Entity {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "tid", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Set<Table2Entity> elements = new HashSet<>();
}
```

However, the set in the entity is always empty, why is that ? 
The above approach works for one to one and many to one relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns, it's not required to do join with sql, to bring one to many relationship for the view entity. I solved it like this:

```
Subselect(
    "SELECT * from table1" 
)
@Entity
@Immutable
class Entity {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "field", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Set<Table2Entity> elements = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I only needed to put column name, on which tables needed to be joined.